# Should I decorate a function?

Tags: python

Trying to determine if I should try to use decorator or some other Pythonic way to reduce code that many of my functions are doing. I would like these functions to be able to call just maybe one other function at the start of each function or somehow "decorate" the start of each function. I have never used decorator before and am struggling to implement this decorate idea in a pythonic way to reduce the common set of share code at each function.

I have many functions that will perform the same set of steps at the start of the function. However, there is some structure concerns of the common code that makes this "decorator" idea difficult :

- The functions are all in child class of a parent class.
- The common commands between the functions reference variable names
  that are   specific to the function (but a subset of the function
  name).
- The common commands need to return to the caller and not execute any
  more of the child function if a certain condition is met. ("if jobj : " block in the sample code)

For variable/attribute examples, child function get_nas_server(self) will utilize "nas_server" variable variants in the common set of code. Subtracting the get_ from the function name reveals the base of the variable name to be used in the common set of code. Example variables names and object attributes derived from "get_nas_server" function name:

nas_server
nas_server.json
self.nas_server  (attribute)

Here is the common code from one of the functions:

```
        ####################################################################
        def get_nas_server(self):
        ####################################################################
            """\nGets COMMAND nas_server and places data into self.nas_server"""

           try:
               self.nas_server
               return self.nas_server
           except AttributeError:
               pass
           self.get_file_cmd('nas_server')
           jobj = self.fresh_json('nas_server.json')
           if jobj :
               self.nas_server = jobj
               return self.nas_server
           self.get_file_cmd('get_nas_server')
```

Everything below that code above in the function is specific to the function purpose and not appropriate for discussion here. Basically I am trying to make all that code above reusable in my functions, but the code has to have the variables and attribute changed depending on the function name.

Thanks for reading if you got this far and thanks for all help.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like something you could define as a helper method in the parent class:

```
class Parent(object):
    def _get_something(name):
        try:
            return getattr(self, name)
        except AttributeError:
            pass
       self.get_file_cmd(name)
       jobj = self.fresh_json(name+'.json')
       if jobj :
           setattr(self, name, jobj)
           return jobj
       self.get_file_cmd('get_'+name)
```

As this snippet demonstrates, you can use the [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr), [`setattr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr) and [`hasattr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hasattr) functions to reference object attributes by name.

Comment: Thanks for the input. The code to be added to the existing function needs to be able return to the original caller and not execute anymore code if specific conditions are met. This "return" if condition requirement does not seem possible with a helper method.

Comment: @Fragtzack True, but you can do that in a couple of lines in the function that calls the helper.

Comment: ok, will try this. In the function that calls this helper, I call this helper with simply a  self._get_something('nas_server') ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a decorator inside your class, if the initial bookkeeping stuff is too specific to that class. Everytime you need to do that initial check inside a class method, you can simply decorate it with the `auto_nas` decorator I have added below. The scope of this wrapper, I am assuming, is specific to this class alone. Otherwise, you can move it outside the class for generality, but remember to change `(self=None)` if you're going to do so.

```
class YourMainClass():
    # This is your main class inside which all the methods are defined.

    def auto_nas(func):
        # This wrapper function will be called instead of your class methods.
        def wrap(self):
            # All your bookkeeping stuff goes here.
            try:
               self.nas_server
               return self.nas_server
            except AttributeError:
               pass
            self.get_file_cmd('nas_server')
            jobj = self.fresh_json('nas_server.json')
            if jobj :
               self.nas_server = jobj
               return self.nas_server
            self.get_file_cmd('get_nas_server')
            # Things went well - we shall call the actual method.
            return func(self)
        return wrap

    @auto_nas
    def get_nas_server(self):
        # This is one of your methods that require bookkeeping
        pass
```

Also, notice the `self` inside the wrapper function. It is automatically passed as an argument by Python, and thus you can access all the instance specific attributes from inside that decorator. Once again, this is appropriate if your decorator must do jobs specific to each instances of your class. If that is not the case, you can simply put all of that code in a function and call it each time whenever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Much thanks to Augurar for pointing in the proper direction. I ended up created a stub method in the parent class. Just needed to call the method with the proper technique to "extend" the parent method. Then calling that stub method from the child class with super() There must be a proper name for this technique? method override? method extend?

Here is the parent class method mostly as Augurar suggested:

```
###########################################################################
def get_stub(self,fcmd):
###########################################################################
    try:
        return getattr(self, fcmd)
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    jobj = self.fresh_json(fcmd + '.json')
    if jobj :
        setattr(self, fcmd, jobj)
        return jobj
    if not self.get_file_cmd(fcmd):
        self.log.error("{} not found".format(fcmd))
        return False
```

Here is the manner in which the child method uses this parent method:

```
####################################################################
def get_nas_server(self):
####################################################################
  super().get_stub('nas_server')
  #bunch of child method specific code below here
```